# Basis and dimension for $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

For a vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$ under usual addition and usual scalar multiplication over $\mathbb{R}$

Why is that a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the set $\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$ and not just $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: isn't the set (1,1) spans the whole $R^2$??

Comment: ...and linearly independent ??

Comment: No. $(1,0)^\top$ and $(0,1)^\top$ span $\mathbb{R}^2$. The vector $(1,1)^\top$ is a linear combination of your basis and therefore it's an element of the span of $(1,0)^\top$ and $(0,1)^\top$.

Comment: okay, that make sense, but if  now it is over complex vector space C, will the basis for R^2 change? I think it changes? now it is like (1,1)^T , only one element. so dim $R^2=1$ but how does this make sense?

Comment: $\dim \Bbb R^2=2$ so you need two vectors. $(1,1)$ alone spans the line $y=x$.

Comment: Anyone knows why dim R^2 changes?

Comment: It does not. Why would it?

Answer (score 1):

The vector $(1,1)$ is not a basis for $\Bbb R^2$ for the simple reason that not every vector in $\Bbb R^2$ can be expressed as a scalar multiple of it.

More generally: a set $\beta \subseteq V$ with elements $\beta_i$ is a basis for a vector space $V$ over a field $F$ if two conditions are met, one of which is that $\rm{span}(\beta) = V$. Or, that is, for every $v \in V$, we can choose $\beta_i$ from $\beta$ such that

$$v = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \beta_i$$

where $\alpha_i \in F$ are scalars. If you can always find scalars $\alpha_i \in F$ such that $v$ is a sum of multiples of those $\beta_i \in \beta$, in other words, then $\beta$ is a vector space for $V$.

However, in the case of $V = \Bbb R^2$ and $\beta = \left\{ (1,1) \right\}$, it is easy to see that this condition is not met. Namely, how would you write $(0,1)$ or $(1,0)$, each elements of $\Bbb R^2$, solely in terms of scalar multiples of elements of $\beta$?

In fact, as it happens: for $V$ a finite-dimensional vector space with dimension $\dim V = n$, it happens that any basis $\beta$ of $V$ satisfies $|\beta| = n = \dim V$. You need one vector in the basis to account for each of the dimensions of the vector space itself, loosely speaking. This is another means by which we see $\left\{ (1,1) \right\}$ is not a basis for $\Bbb R^2$, since it has cardinality $1$, where $\Bbb R^2$ has dimension $2$ over $\Bbb R$. (Or infinite dimensionality over the smaller subfields of $\Bbb R$ like $\Bbb Q$, but that's another matter altogether.)

To reiterate, to perhaps clear up some confusion you have in your comments: your dimension is always with respect to the field $F$ your vector space $V$ is over, usually denoted with a subscript. For instance:

$$\dim \limits_{\Bbb R} \Bbb C = 2 \text{ whereas } \dim \limits_{\Bbb C} \Bbb C = 1$$

Why is this the case? Well, this goes back to the fact that linear combinations of your spanning set take scalars from the field $F$.

If we're only allowed real scalars, then $\left\{1,i\right\}$ are a spanning set for $\Bbb C$. After all, every $z \in \Bbb C$ may be expressed as $z = x+iy$ for $x,y \in \Bbb R$. You can't have a dimension of $1$ because then your claimed spanning set would only span a line in $\Bbb C$ and not the entirety of $\Bbb C$ itself.

On the other hand, if we're allowed complex scalars, then of course $\dim_\Bbb C \Bbb C = 1$. That is because $z = z \cdot 1$ for every $z \in \Bbb C$: that is, we treat $z$ as the scalar in the case on the right-hand side. Of course, that also means the standard basis is $\left\{1\right\}$ in that case.

(And of course, more generally: $F$ is always able to be regarded as a vector space over itself for any field $F$, with basis $\left\{1\right\}$. Then $\dim_F F = 1$.)